# I can't get Excel to create a new worksheet in a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, hyperlink, cell, worksheet

I have maintained a 1st worksheet "Master" where column A is the product code.
2nd worksheet is "Template".

The objective was to create new worksheet from cell value in column A, copy data from template sheet to the new sheet, rename the worksheet and create hyperlink to cell value so if I click on the cell it will take to the new worksheet.

Now it is giving error while crating new worsheet. Secondly when I add more data to column A and run macro again , it is not creating new sheets.

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
   Dim c As Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A5:A50")
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With c
            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End With
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change **ALL** the data in `A5:A50`, you will not be able to run it a second time. Excel requires a unique name for each sheet. What you could do, however, is create an error handler for when a sheet name already exists and skip that cell in the loop. Furthermore, if you have a blank cell and try to set the sheet name to that cell, it will also error out.

For a functional answer, you could use something like this

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
Dim c As Range
Dim errTest As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo eHandler

For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A5:A50")
    With c
        Set errTest = Sheets(.Value)
        If .Value <> "" And errTest Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = .Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End If
    End With
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
eHandler:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
    Set errTest = Nothing
    Resume Next
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: STILL HAS AN ERROR WHILE SAVING THE EXCEL DOCUMENT AND OPENING AGAIN AND ADDING MORE TEXT TO COLUMN A, ERROR 1004

Answer (score 0):

... and if you don't already have a **hyperlink back to the master sheet** in your template, you may add one to each new sheet like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Master'!A" & c.Row, TextToDisplay:="Back"
```